# In React application, Images cannot show when an image url is string property of a object

Tags: html, reactjs

I cannot show the image when the image url is string property in a object.
For example:

```js
import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react';

const profile = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'John',
      photo: './asset/images/user.png'
    })
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <img src={user.photo} alt="photo" />
      <p>{user.name}</p>  
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Of course I can solve this by importing image object like `import img from './assets/images/user.png'`. But I need to know how to show image without importing it.

Does anyone solve the problem?

Comment: did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can see one example working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sinoussi-ikown?file=/src/App.js

The main problem is you're trying to access the image as a relative route from your component.

But, when you want to do something like that your component can be anywhere in the application. So, the way to do it is:

- Include your images in `public/`
- Access your images using the absolute route from `/public`